# Ripping on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat

Why can I open a bag of potato Chips and not rip  toilet paper?

Comment: Because you're bad at ripping things??

Comment: Your joke got snubbed @DoubleAA

Answer (score 4):

A discussion about opening a bag of potato chips, according to various poskim, can be found on the [YUTorah.org website](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/714260/Rabbi_Eli_Ozarowski/Opening_Bags_on_Shabbas). A [related discussion by Rabbi Dovid Ostroff regarding tearing toilet paper](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/ostroff/archives/shabbos3_13.htm) is also available.

From the first link:

> Furthermore, there may be no violation
>   of koreya here either: the Tosefta
>   (Shabbos 17:9), cited in the Mishnah
>   Berurah (314:25), allows tearing the
>   leather covering of a barrel without
>   concern for koreya, and many
>   understand the reason to be that even
>   if the covering is not destroyed, it
>   is batel (subordinate) to the barrel,
>   and tearing the covering is therefore
>   like the mere removing of a nut from
>   its shell (though see Chazon Ish above
>   and 61:2 for a different explanation).
>   Some poskim claim that our case is
>   comparable, and thus permit tearing
>   the bag (see Igros Moshe, Orach Chaim
>   1:122, R’ Neustadt in The Weekly
>   Halachah Discussion p.134-138, and
>   Tikunim u-Miluim to Shemiras Shabbos
>   ke-Hilchasah 9:11). Others (cited in
>   Shemiras Shabbos ke-Hilchasah, ad loc.
>   note 11) employ other factors for
>   leniency, combining the opinions that
>   the biblical prohibition of koreya
>   only applies when doing so al menas
>   litfor (in order to sew it later),
>   that it is not koreya when the tear
>   itself constitutes a tikkun, and that
>   koreya is not violated when tearing
>   one entity into two (rather than the
>   tear separating two attached items).

If we take this first reason, we can understand why it would not apply to toilet paper. It is not batel. I'm uncertain about how it differs given the other two reasons.

Answer (score 2):

You ARE allowed to rip toilet paper, but only as long as you do not rip from the perforated lines on the toilet paper.
I think that the problem from ripping the paper at the perforation is that it constitutes measuring, which is a melacha. I don't know the source of this answer, it's just what I heard from a couple orthodox Rabbis.

Comment: It could also be a problem of "tikun maneh" which is a subcategory of "makeh b'patish".

Comment: [Here](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/?id=7243) is a source, which actually notes both.

Comment: @JNF, both what? It mentions "מתקן מנא" but not "measuring" AFAICT.

Comment: @msh210 both paper and food packages.

Comment: It seems like you can't rip toilet paper even if you don't use the perforated lines because it becomes a utensil: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/484233/jewish/Am-I-allowed-to-rip-something.htm

Comment: It's derech lechiluch, which the Shulchan Aruch paskins is mutar.  Additionally, as stated above, many poskim hold that ripping toilet paper is at most a rabbinic restriction, which would mean that since the Sages permit us to be over rabbinic restrictions in order to honor human dignity.  So in the case of toilet paper you have a few ideas to be lenient.  In answer to an above post about perforated lines, many poskim hold that is only if you intend to use the perforation.  Usually when ripping toilet paper you don't care so much if it's on the line, so it would be mutar.

Answer (score 1):

there is a leniency that you are allowed to tear for the purpose of eating food so long as you destroy the vessel (and not tear letters!!). i believe you must tear the bag in a way that makes it unusable

Comment: Does that mean you can't open packages of snacks by pulling on the two sides and have to rip it (should this be a separate question?)

Comment: @yydl i think u can since u are destroying the vessel

Comment: Where is this Heter stated about food I have heard and never seen it

Comment: avrohom, mi.yodeya is a forum for answers with sources when possible. "They say", "I have heard", "I once learned" "There is" are all fine when accompanied by sources. I am not saying I have been perfect in this regard but for common she'ailos such as this, a little effort with regard to sources would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: does anyone know where the heter for food allowing ripping on SHABBOS and not YOM TOV where I know it exists comes from

Comment: @yahu rabbi shusterman said so in his shiurim on 39 melachos on chabad.org

Comment: @simchas shabbas and yom tov i believe they apply the same way

Comment: I Belive you are in error we are allowed to cook on yom Tov for food and we most definitely may not do that on Shabbos

Comment: avrohom, why not add in the fact that you heard it from Rav Shusterman in the actual answer?