Alzheimer's and Dementia and counting for a minyan
I have tried to find any discussion or responsa on whether someone with dementia or alzheimer's would count for a minyan.
The obvious question is, are they with it enough to know what is being said, respond to amen etc.
Maybe it's taken on a case by case basis, maybe not. Either way, what are the halachic principles to apply to this question?

Is someone with dementia or alzheimer's not the very definition of a shoteh? https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/27891

That's the kicker. It depends how severe the condition is; if it gets to the point of shoteh, then no. Before that, yes.

@Shalom Is it that simple? So do you think this question should just be closed as a dupe of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14371/who-is-a-shoteh? Ideally, I'd like to find a specific responsa to the subject

So the question is really -- at what level of dementia/Alzheimer's is someone exempt from all mitzvos. At which point they could not execute/receive a Gett, nor count for a minyan (if male), and many other things. It's hard to have clear lines. Rabbi Broyde mentioned that the Beis Din of America had someone diagnosed with early, but very rapidly-worsening, Alzheimer's. The goal was to give the Gett before it was too late, but no sooner than was truly necessary. That's as far as he described it.
